# How to Post map data inside ArrayList as form-data by postman

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, postman, postman-native-app

i am Posting a Map data as ArrayList.
So i have tried it by Raw body. but i need to post it as Form-Data.
I tried it by many ways but i didn't get result. if any one knows the solution, how to do it. please give me solution.

and here is my code belove.

```
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(value = "name")
    private String name;

    @Field(value = "description")
    private String description;

        @Field(value = "attributes")
        private List<Map<String, String>> attributes = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    this is what i am sending in Body Raw i want to post it by Form-Data

    {
        "name":"Fourth Template",
        "description":"covers most of selected attributes",
        "attributes": [
        {
          "attributeId": "5d4284807748181cbc8a8277",
          "selectedDataSource": "collections"
        },
         {
          "attributeId": "5d4284807748181cbc8a8277",
          "selectedDataSource": "paycom"
        },
         {
          "attributeId": "5d4284807748181cbc8a8277",
          "selectedDataSource": "originations"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of posting it as raw data, in postman you've form-data beside raw data, you can post your formData through it.

See the image link for your reference:

[image: Posting a Map data as ArrayList]

Comment: Hi I Thanks for your reply. i tried in your way but i am getting response in this way.{
            "id": "5d42d6c6f139d532b88445fe",
            "name": "Fif",
            "description": "added most selected dataSources",
           "attributes": [
                {},
                {},
                {}
                 ]
        }
}

Comment: its taking null map key and values

Comment: @ghaluprabha instead of using Form-data use **X-www-form-urluncoded**.. Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

show your controller method, try add @RequestBody Entity or @RequestBody Map map.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Reply. i used This format earlier using @RequestBody As Raw ,but i want to post it by form data, i didn't know the Form-data format in which format